# Помогите разобраться с установкой угла через quaternion

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotation

Привет всем!

Задача стоит такая:

Есть куб, который мы вращаем по 1-й из 3-х осей. Условия вращения такие: ось по которой мы вращаем куб считаетя свободной.

Углы на которые повернут куб должны быть кратны 90 градусам. Но тут есть исключение, одна грань куба должна быть параллельно игроку (вернее плоскости экрана игрока).

Теперь проблема: вращать куб вдоль 1-й из трех осей относительно игрока получилось:

```
myTransform - player
rigidBody / rigidTransform - куб
    void FixedUpdate () {
            if (rigidBody){
                Vector3 euler = rigidTransform.localEulerAngles;// rigidBody.rotation.eulerAngles;// rigidTransform.localRotation.eulerAngles;//

                Vector3 playerEulars = myTransform.eulerAngles;//rigidBody.rotation; 
                Vector3 localAxis;
                Vector3 eulerAngleVelocity;// = localAxis * delta;

                if (axisIndex==0) {
                    localAxis = rigidTransform.InverseTransformPoint (Vector3.up + rigidTransform.position);

                    eulerAngleVelocity = localAxis * delta;
                    euler.x = Mathf.Round (euler.x / 90f) * 90f;
                    euler.z = Mathf.Round (euler.z / 90f) * 90f;

                    Debug.Log ("OY");
                } else {
                    if (axisIndex==1) {// z axis
                        localAxis = rigidTransform.InverseTransformPoint(myTransform.TransformPoint (Vector3.forward)+(rigidBody.position-myTransform.position));

                        eulerAngleVelocity = localAxis * delta;
                        float displacement = euler.y - myTransform.eulerAngles.y;
                        euler.y = playerEulars.y + Mathf.Round (displacement / 90f) * 90f;
                        euler.x = Mathf.Round (euler.x / 90f) * 90f;

                        Debug.Log ("OZ");
                    } else {
                        if (axisIndex == 2) {
                            localAxis = rigidTransform.InverseTransformPoint (myTransform.TransformPoint (Vector3.right) + (rigidBody.position - myTransform.position));

                            eulerAngleVelocity = localAxis * delta;
                            float displacement = euler.y - myTransform.eulerAngles.y;
                            euler.y = playerEulars.y + Mathf.Round (displacement / 90f) * 90f;
                            euler.z = Mathf.Round (euler.z / 90f) * 90f;

                            Debug.Log ("OX");
                        } else {
                            eulerAngleVelocity = Vector3.zero;
                        }
                    }
                }

                rigidBody.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (rigidBody.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(euler), 5f*Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                if (isLocalPlayer) {
                    Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngleVelocity * 5000f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                    rigidBody.rotation *= deltaRotation;
                }
            }
        }
```

1) Куб постоянно одной из граней повернут к игроку
2) Вращается вдоль одной из осей
3) Пытается вернуться на угол кратный 90 градусам по остальным осям, по которым его не вращают.

Проблема в чем, куб начинает иногда передергивать если его пытаться вращать т.к. вращения в euler приводят к этому(он неверно пытается вернуть угол)... Понимаете что происходит? Посоветуйте как исправить это)

Answer (score 1):

Избавляйтесь от вращения через углы Эйлера. Если хотите чтобы все работало без ошибок нужно все делать через `Quaternion`. Вот неплохое объяснение [что это такое](https://habrahabr.ru/post/183908/). Когда вам нужно повернуть объект на заданный угол делаете Quaternion при помощи метода

`Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(float angle, Vector3 axis);`

Теперь берете текущее вращение `transform.rotation` и умножаете на полученный `q`. В результате ваш объект к имеющемуся вращению добавит ваш заданный поворот.

Еще в вашем коде смущает что вы пытаетесь `rigidbody` вращать, если у вас куб не кинематика это тоже может влиять, потому что ваши изменения положения объекта будут противоречить с работой физики.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я разобрался с тем что такое кватернионы.  Не так давно понял что между углами эйлера и кватернионами не стоит строить отображения (до этого я упорно думал что эти множества как-то можно отобразить друг в друга чтобы это выглядело адекватно). "Еще в вашем коде смущает что вы пытаетесь rigidbody вращать" - а вот это не понял. Почему?

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь заставить куб доворачиваться до ближайшего угла кратного 90 градусам. Ну как пытаюсь, читаю книгу по кватернионам, на gamedev.ru дают советы, но пока все тщетно

Comment: Если у вас у `rigidbody` стоит признак `Is Kinematic` то анимировать через вращение `transform.rotation` вполне нормально, а вот когда вы пытаетесь объект который обрабатывается в физике Unity(без такой галочки) перемещаться в нужную позицию таким способом, то фактически получаете телепорт и движок физики начинает медленно сходить с ума. В таком случае предполагается что вы вращаете и двигаете объекты при помощи силы. В вашем случае можно сделать объект на кинематике и тогда все будет нормально

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вращать куб относительно какого-то обьекта не нужно вовсе писать никакого кода. Достаточно поместить куб в иерархии как подобьект "игрока".

А потом через  Quaternion.AngleAxis(float angle, Vector3 axis); ставить значения кратные 90 градусам.